# Unable replace characters from one string to another - Is it a Javascript bug?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to make an effect of replacing one string with another, but without completely erasing the contents of the first one. As if it were a special effect, each letter of a string is transformed into another word. At first I'm trying to do it like a typewriter, but later I want to do it randomly. However, I can't get it to work, it looks like it's a bug.

```js
let title1 = "Your sales place";
let title2 = "Software Hub";

var k = 0;
var speed = 150;

function typeWriter() {
  if (k < title1.length) {
    if (k >= title2.length) {
      title2 += title1.charAt(k);
    }
    title2 = title2.replace(title2.charAt(k), title1.charAt(k));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = title2;
    k += 1;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

output:

```
YO AESRL SUPLACE
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: im expecting title1 output.

Comment: Don't always expect the bug is from the language....  It happens but not that often...

Answer (score 3):

`replace` replaces the *first* occurrence of the character, which is not necessarily the one at index `k`.

Instead of mutating `title2`, I would recommend to simply do

```
….innerHTML = title2.slice(0, k) + title1.slice(k);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Bergi. I think i fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code for what i'm waiting. Sorry for the mistake.

```
import { onMount } from "svelte";

    let title1 = "Your sales place";
    let title2 = "Software Hub";
    var part = "";
    var k = 0;
    var speed = 150;

    onMount(() => {
        typeWriter();
    });

    function sliceReplace(origin, final, k) {

        part = part.slice(0,k);
        part += final.charAt(k) + origin.slice(k+1);
        return part;

    }

    function typeWriter() {
        if (k < title1.length) {
            if (k >= title2.length) {
                title2 += title1.charAt(k);
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sliceReplace(title2, title1, k);
            k += 1;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution with the least modification.
The problem with your code is using `String.prototype.charAt` to find and replace your character, and it finds the first occurrence of a character. So when a character is repeated in your string, charAt will find and replace the first occurrence, not the other ones.

So you can define a function like `replaceAt` below, to replace a character at a specific position, and use that.

```js
let title1 = "Your sales place";
let title2 = "Software Hub";

String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index +   replacement.length);
}

var k = 0;
var speed = 150;

function typeWriter() {
  if (k < title1.length) {
    if (k >= title2.length) {
      title2 += title1[k];
    } else {
      title2 = title2.replaceAt(k, title1[k]);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = title2;
    k += 1;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

However, I would recommend that you do not use global variables as counters when recursively calling a function, instead, pass that variable to your function:

```js
let title1 = "Your sales place";
let title2 = "Software Hub";

var speed = 150;

String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

function typeWriter(k) {
  if (k < title1.length) {
    let title = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML
    if (k >= title.length) {
      title += title1[k];
    } else {
      title = title.replaceAt(k, title1[k]);
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = title;
    setTimeout(() => {typeWriter(k+1)}, speed);
  }
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = title2;
setTimeout(() => {typeWriter(0);}, speed)
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its nice to have many solutions.